# EntityManager query cannot resolve property

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager, joincolumn

I am using JPA to query an OracleSQL database.
However, I am getting the error:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: CLIENT_ID of: com.fdmgroup.pojo.File [SELECT c FROM com.fdmgroup.pojo.File c WHERE c.CLIENT_ID = :clientId]
```

When I write the following query

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT c FROM XD_FILES c WHERE c.CLIENT_ID = :clientId";
TypedQuery<File> query = em.createQuery(sqlQuery, File.class);
query = query.setParameter("clientId", clientId);
ArrayList<File> clientFiles = (ArrayList<File>) query.getResultList();
```

File has this column

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Client.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "CLIENT_ID")
private Client client;
```

I am unsure why as it appears to have the field "client" linked to "CLIEND_ID".

Comment: What is the column name?

Comment: your "sqlQuery" is SQL but you use the API for JPQL!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to mention the property name in the query and not the column name.

So the query should look like the following:

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT c FROM XD_FILES c WHERE c.clientId = :clientId";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems native query and not a JPQL, you can solve this in two ways.

1) change em.createQuery(sqlQuery, File.class); to em.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery, File.class);

2) Change your query from native query to JPQL, your query should be like

```
select c from File c where c.client.clientID=:clientId
(Assuming clientID is primary key column name in Client class)
```